# React Native, render a local image

Tags: xcode, image, render, react-native

I'm trying to add an image in my app but it doesn't work. Below, this is my code :

```
return(
    <View>
    <Text style={styles.text}>ABCDEFG</Text>
    <Image
        style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
        source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>

    <Image style={{width: 400, height: 400}} source={require('image!download')} />
    </View>
    );
```

Text is displaying. Below it, Facebook React logo is displaying. However, my download image doesn't show up. It's embedded because if I'm changing "download" to "mypicture" or something else, after refreshing, I obtain the following error : Requiring unknown module "image!mypicture". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.

I've restarted XCode and even my computer. I've commented Facebook logo just in case. I've seen in March, people had issues to render an image. Does someone has an idea ? I'm not familiar with XCode.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What picture are you trying to render?  One that's been downloaded, or one that's in the file system?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `xcassets`, make sure the name of the image file itself is the same as the name in the `xcassets` section.

So in this case...the name of the image file should also be `download.png`. Make sure you use Xcode to add remove those images because it writes to a JSON file and just renaming the files on the file system won't update that file.

If you still have trouble with `xcassets`, you can just drop the images into your project in some group and access them by filename in React Native. You don't *need* `xcassets` although it has some benefits (like different resolution management).

Comment: [The Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) are a great resource here.  In particular, there is a helpful image to walk you through adding an image to `xcassets`.